# Trouble installing Contrail bundle

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, juju, maas

I am trying to install the Contrail bundle (by Robert Ayres) using Juju. After setting up containers and VMs, it begins to set up each of those services. When I run juju status I get the following message: [hook failed: install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PU4M.png)

I went into the VM and pulled out the log file. Turns out the VM couldnt locate Contrail packages.

Anyone else facing the same problem? I later added the opencontrail ppa to the sources list but it didnt help. The juju installation prcoess keeps cycling as it tries to intall again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you're using the right bundle(s).

When using OpenContrail, the latest package build from OpenContrail PPA is 2.21 and can be deployed with OpenStack Juno using this bundle:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sdn-charmers/+junk/contrail-deployer/view/head:/bundles/contrail-trusty-juno.yaml

I've tested this deploys fine using Juju 2.1.1, MAAS 2.1.3. It should just work.

---

If deploying Contrail (requires license + package files from Juniper - https://www.juniper.net/support/downloads/?p=contrail#sw), you can deploy Contrail 3.2+ using an OpenStack Mitaka bundle:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sdn-charmers/+junk/contrail-deployer/view/head:/bundles/contrail-trusty-mitaka.yaml

**Note:** You will need to create a local apt repo containing Contrail 3.x+ packages before deploying, as detailed here - https://github.com/tonyliu0592/opencontrail/blob/master/juju/juju-contrail.md#12-contrail-repository. Then update the bundle pointing contrail charms to your local package repo using 'install-sources', 'install-keys' options. For example:

```
contrail-configuration:
  charm: cs:~sdn-charmers/trusty/contrail-configuration
  options:
    install-keys: |
      - |
        -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        Version: GnuPG v1

        mQENBFZDkpsBCAC+T+UOOLUky331HZk8RbfF7mQ35nwH1PGl2vHM6RWdqayLK4aV
        1uUNGzI3UJw0YVCMmqJSlNfU58GhxEZ/cRbVjnZ6ebAIWRGepsMYWDlA960ornnL
        VCRbr6yvHU06MSS8yl0X43QL2yGdBRiC5EAPEAawDOTMk0RxJ1AvMDHmnKommoQG
        MWJ5zKL+fYSiNEPxQ2/nYd2jVXK4a1jP8c4LcvMdo8uxrEHklr/81wX+UKZYzuZP
        bWQmiXiZzhQD2qz7IgZDaBKVEH4b2xMjilaPc2JOH0hHdP0M33PUOvCbpXQAYOok
        kzqFpglZq1mZmM1ba6x37E07YpOvNWN0kE9DABEBAAG0CENvbnRyYWlsiQE4BBMB
        AgAiBQJWQ5KbAhsDBgsJCAcDAgYVCAIJCgsEFgIDAQIeAQIXgAAKCRBmWWjLMSv5
        wDrYB/4nMGcDVFRGU4tvIykhu/l6J6uNunpACL5HrdxC93PrThB2EgJXgnPpE/O+
        KtjN2JKkSs4ehQy0wRMHc1eM/pQ1GRw4QV6vxO1FPT+y8BMdYkuwqd3uM22wg9mZ
        yKvLtWBhMEu9nAPsTSVaT7Yw1z319Nr7JP+0mRCmlkLjuQUF2RcMwH59XH+8Lpev
        MJEGdDcwWifPiO83ycBTQ760miz4B4inUWLYZ11lW/tXRSNG+o4QjemF5mWbPO+H
        knwC/9eukDath9q7itLbJsDbam0/2KCTPxly1sk6E9hCNSIxlNT6ZnnnorLUoSqH
        cTfEFYBDWmyhtqzHcfqocnBaPZT8
        =rMS6
        -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    install-sources: |
      - "deb http://192.168.122.1:8080/3.2.0.0-19-mitaka /"
    openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-mitaka
  num_units: 1
  to: [ "lxd:0" ]
```